# PHP Regex to find if string is formatted with commas and semicolons

Tags: php, regex, string

I need to find if a string is formatted in the following way:

```
text1,x%;text2,y%
```

So, these strings must be valid:

```
example, 10%; test, 22%; another, 90%

another example, 11.5%; yet other example, 91%

another, 11%; other example, 11.2%

example2, 20%
```

And the following must be invalid:

```
example3; 10%, test3, 22%; another3, 90%

example4; 20%

example5, 11%; test 5, 123%

another fail example, 11,5%; yet other example, 91%
```

I know some regex but this validation I don't even know how to start.

EDIT: Added more examples.

Comment: So what is it `anything, anything;`?

Comment: You seem to have a conflict. `example2, 20%` passes, `example4; 20%` doesn't.

Comment: @chris85 it's a name and the percentage of the profits this person will be recieving.

sln No, it's not a conflict. If only one person exists, the percentage still need to be separated by comma, not semicolon.

Comment: Actually I meant this passes `example2, 20%` but this `example5, 11%; test 5, 123%` doesn't. You should describe exactly what `Text`, and `x`% are composed of.

Comment: Guessing game. But, I've learned something. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
^[\w\s]+,\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?%(?:;\s*[\p{L}\s]+,\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)*$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bB4pE4/2)

**Regex explanation:**

Basically, it consists of 2 parts, the one before `;` and the rest optional sequences.

- `^` - Beginning of a string
- `[\w\s]+` - 1 or more alphanumeric or whitespace characters followed by...
- `,` - a comma, then
- `\s*` - optional whitespace
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?%` - a float or integer number (decimal part is optional due to `?`) and a percentage sign
- `(?:;\s*[\p{L}\s]+,\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?%)*` - the 2nd part that matches 0 or more sequences of...

  - `;\s*` - a semi-colon followed by optional whitespace
  - `[\p{L}\s]+` - 1 or more letters (`\p{L}`) or whitespace
  - `,\s*` - comma followed by optional whitespace
  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?%` - a float or integer number (decimal part is optional) and a percentage sign
- `$` - End of string

Comment: Many thanks, but I need to apologize because I didn't included enough examples in my questions, sorry.

Comment: I will only provide explanation if this regex works for you - it is long, and I am not sure about `[\p{L}\s]+` in the second part.